# Python code for eliminating options for random intergers as they get picked

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

My goal is to write code that picks several random numbers from a range without repeating any previously chosen numbers.
I figured out a functional solution for my problem but it seems very bulky and there must be a way to do this in fewer lines. Mine feels brute force and not very elegant and becomes super unwieldy if stretched to larger ranges and repetitions. Would love any suggestions for cleaning up what I already have.

```
import random

key1 = random.randint(1, 4)
while True:
    key2 = random.randint(1, 4)
    if key2 != key1:
        break
while True:
    key3 = random.randint(1, 4)
    if key3 != key1 and key3 != key2:
        break
while True:
    key4 = random.randint(1, 4)
    if key4 != key1 and key4 != key2 and key4 != key3:
        break

key_order = [key1, key2, key3, key4]
print(key_order)
```

If it means totally taking my code apart and rebuilding it, that is fine. I am here to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- > if key4 != key1 and key4 != key2 and key4 != key3:

  If you append to `key_order` upon picking a non-duplicate value you can just use `in` instead.
- You can then more simply use a for loop to select the number of keys to output.

```py
key_order = []
for _ in range(4):
    while True:
        key = random.randint(1, 4)
        if key not in key_order:
            key_order.append(key)
            break
```

---

- You can just use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) or [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and follow Python's "batteries included" ethos.

```py
key_order = random.sample(range(1, 5), 4)
```

```py
key_order = random.shuffle(range(1, 5))
```

---

Your algorithm is known as the naive shuffle, because the algorithm is very simple but also very slow. If you want to implement the shuffle yourself [there's a very clear visual explanation on how the Fisher-Yates shuffle works](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/).

Whatever you do you should remove the `while` loop by only picking a random number from the values you have left. You can do so by building a list of options to pick from by [`list.pop`ing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) when you `key_order.append(key)`.

Whilst `pop` is less expensive then your while loop when shuffling, `pop` is still expensive. So we can change `append` and `pop` to a swap operation. For the first selection we swap `0` with `random.randrange(0, 4)`, then for the second selection `1` with `random.randrange(1, 4)`... Getting the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

```py
values = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(values)):
    j = random.randrange(i, len(values))
    values[i], values[j] = values[j], values[i]
```

Comment: This was incredibly informative (and practical). I greatly appreciate your feedback.